# What type of question is too simple?

Tags: discussion

This is probably a duplicate of "[Is this site only for "expert-level questions"?](https://economics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30/is-this-site-only-for-expert-level-questions)" but somehow I wasn't able to see from the question (and its answers) what we do with very simple questions, now that we are in the public beta.

"[what is the optimum level of production?](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/5190/what-is-the-optimum-level-of-production)" is the perfect example for that - it is really basic (imho not even an Econ 101 question). However, I don't know if I should vote to close the question or not. The OP has clearly tried to answer the question by himself and knows that something is wrong. So the only reason I see for closing this question is: It is too basic.

Comment: Related: http://meta.economics.stackexchange.com/questions/142/what-level-are-we-aiming-for-now-we-are-in-public-beta